# Node server.js Process Not able to Kill in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux, node.js, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have to go for a fresh deployment and `git clone` a new repository inside my EC2 instance.

We did 
`git clone XXXXX`

Moved to the respective folder

`cd XXXXX`

And Try running

`node server.js`

The thing is, this starts my server, but no changes are reflected when I hit the AWS Instance IP/ Public URL on my browser.

When I did a

`ps aux | grep node` to find if any other node process is on, I found this

`nodejs  9183  0.4  ?  Sl   10:28   0:13 node server.js`

If I do a 
`kill -9 9183`

And then again do a 
`ps aux | grep node`

Now I see the same `node server.js` process with a different `PID`

Not understanding what's happening here.

Thanks in advance and please help.

Comment: Check whether there is parent process by using `pstree -p`.

Comment: Yes. `|-su(9181)--sh(9182)---node(9183)+-{node}(9184)
       |                                  |-{node}(9185)
       |                                  |-{node}(9186)
       |                                  |-{node}(9187)
       |                                  |-{node}(9188) `

Comment: Trying to kill it says permission denied.